# Typo3 Powermail: Export of multiple forms not working - How to add Translations

Tags: typo3, powermail

I have a contact form in different languages. All Forms (1 per language) store their data on a certain page. When I click "Mails" and that storage page, I see a list of all messages from all forms - so far so good.

But when I click CSV Export, I only get the data from one language. After a while of debugging I think I have found the reason - this is because the export service collects the fields from the first message and based on that field list it builds all the other rows. As other messages are from different forms (i.e. languages) there are no corresponding fields for those messages and they are not exported.

Have a look at https://github.com/Intera/typo3-extension-powermail/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Service/ExportService.php --> see function getDefaultFieldListFrom**First**Mail

Now I am writing to SO instead of Github Bugs, because I still think that there is something wrong with my setup, as Powermail is quite widely used and such an error would have been reported earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the way I set up the translations of the Powermail forms. I have created a different form for each language, which is not the correct way to do it.

I have found a video which describes the correct process: https://vimeo.com/268654409 .
In the case that the video gets removed, here are some screenshots:

1.) navigate to "LIST" on the the page of your form, select your form and click "Create new Record".

[image]

2.) Add a new record "Alternative Page Language"

[image]

3.) Select the desired language for the new record and name it properly:

[image]

4.) Now you should have a new localization in your powermail fields:

[image]

Click on that localization entry to edit / translate it.